# Error in a generic method declared in a generic class in java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following program.

```
class Generic1<T> {
    T t1;
    public Generic1(T t) {
        this.t1=t;
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    public <T> void set(T t){
        this.t1=t;
    }

    public T get(){
        return this.t1;
    }

}

public class GenericFinal { 
    public static void main(String args[]){
        <some statements..>
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, it throws the following error:

GenericFinal.java:11: error: incompatible types: T#1 cannot be converted to T#2
                this.t1=t;
                        ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method set(T#1)
    T#2 extends Object declared in class Generic1
1 error

If I understand the error message correctly, it says that: There can not be a  generic method defined inside a generic class whose type variable names (in the case: T) are common between them.

Can someone please conform whether I am correct here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just change it to `public void set(T t) {`

Answer (score 2):

Replace you method :

```
public <T> void set(T t){
    this.t1=t;
}
```

with

```
public void set(T t) {
    this.t1 = t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joban for looking at my question!!    If I change it to "public void set(T t)", my method no longer will be generic, I believe.  What if I need to do to keep my method generic ? Could you please suggest. Thanks!!

Comment: Your method is still generic as it does not know what type of input it will get.
When you create an object of your class with its generic type for example,

1) Generic1<String> obj = new Generic1<>();
Then your method behaves like set(String t)

2) Generic1<Integer> obj2 = new Generic1<>();
Then your method behaves like set(Integer t)

Comment: It is technically not a "generic method", but what you want is not a "generic method" but rather a non-generic method inside a generic class, and this is what he's showing.